# Overflowing data values when input

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am facing problem as the error message show that data limit is exceeding.

i have tried changing the format of the datatime into many such and finally i landed onto this.

```
<div class="form-group-inner">
   <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
          <label class="login2 pull-right pull-right-pro">Start Time</label>
       </div>
          <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
             <input type="time" id="Timefrom" name="Timefrom" 
              min="6:00" max="20:00">
          </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group-inner">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
         <label class="login2 pull-right pull-right-pro">Startdate</label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
         <input type="date" id="Startdate" name="Startdate"
          value="2019-06-29" min="2019-01-01" max="2019-12-31">
     </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["Timefrom"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["Startdate"]))
   {
     string[] rdate = fc["Startdate"].Split('-');
     model.Timefrom = Convert.ToDateTime(rdate[2] + "-" + rdate[1] + "-" + rdate[0] +  " " + fc["Timefrom"])
   }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing ?

Comment: "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: 'SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM"

This exception is coming when i type values in form.

Comment: what value you are getting in `model.Timefrom` ? What values you are getting in `fc` and `rdate` ? Which line of code gives the error?

Answer (score 0):

C# does not support datetime format "dd-mm-yy hh:mm". Please rewrite your code as follow

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["Timefrom"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(fc["Startdate"]))
   {
     string[] rdate = fc["Startdate"].Split('-');
     model.Timefrom = Convert.ToDateTime(rdate[0] + "-" + rdate[1] + "-" + rdate[2] +  " " + fc["Timefrom"])
   }
```